# BlackBerry supported image effect

Tags: blackberry

Can anyone tell me which image effects, like sepia or flip, and which image properties, like hue and saturation, can be implemented on BlackBerry devices?

Comment: Not sure that "Reply immediately" is going to help your cause.

Comment: I mean which image effects are possible and which are not on Blackberry???

Answer (score 1):

All of the image effects you mentioned are *possible* on BlackBerry as it is fairly easy to manipulate the raw bytes of a Bitmap, however you will have to write your own code or use an [image manipulation library](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=j2me%20image%20manipulation%20library) to achieve the effects you want.

Comment: Thanks..                                                  1.Sepia    2.Charcoal   3.Sketch    4.Grayscale   5.Monochrome   6.Oil paint   7.Emboss  8.Negative   9.Flip  10.Flop                These image effects I want to implement in Blackberry ....Can I implement all these in Blackberry..or not?  If not which are not possible?

Comment: As I said in my original answer, YES it is possible to implement all of the effects you mention.

Answer (score 0):

All of them can be implemented. But it's not that easy, because it will take a lot of work and time. You'll have to manipulate the images as being bytes; which is not simple to produce such effects but achievable/feasible.

Comment: can u give me example of sepia effect or any other effect in blackberry?  so I get the idea of other effects...